# Convert bones to meshes

Tags: mesh

I want to use the blender built-in skeleton as a character - is there a way to convert the bones to concretes meshes?[image]

Comment: I don't think so, but I believe a script could be created to represent the armature structure as a mesh...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was not able to find an addon for that and as it is very close from [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74735/create-mesh-depending-on-rest-position-not-pose-position). Here is an operator to do that (nearly, as the bone shape is not exactly the same).

[image]

The code is commented below. To use it, copy the code in a text view and run the script.

Then in the 3D view, select your armature, hit <kbd>space</kbd> and type "MeshFromArmature" and validate.

The result is a rigged mesh mimicking the armature shape.

If you want to enhance the bone shape, the code is isolated in one function 'boneGeometry' with the needed parameters.

If the comments in the code are not clear enough, please tell.

#### 2.79 Version

```
import bpy
import mathutils 
from mathutils import Vector 
from math import *

def CreateMesh():

    obj = bpy.context.active_object

    if obj == None:
        print( "No selection" )
    elif obj.type != 'ARMATURE':
        print( "Armature expected" )
    else:
        processArmature( bpy.context, obj )

#Create the base object from the armature
def meshFromArmature( arm ):
    name = arm.name + "_mesh"
    meshData = bpy.data.meshes.new( name + "Data" )
    meshObj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, meshData )
    meshObj.matrix_world = arm.matrix_world.copy()
    return meshObj

#Create the bone geometry (vertices and faces)
def boneGeometry( l1, l2, x, z, baseSize, l1Size, l2Size, base ):
    x1 = x * baseSize * l1Size 
    z1 = z * baseSize * l1Size

#    x2 = x * baseSize * l2Size 
#    z2 = z * baseSize * l2Size
    
    x2 = Vector( (0, 0, 0) )
    z2 = Vector( (0, 0, 0) )

    verts = [
        l1 - x1 + z1,
        l1 + x1 + z1,
        l1 - x1 - z1,
        l1 + x1 - z1,
        l2 - x2 + z2,
        l2 + x2 + z2,
        l2 - x2 - z2,
        l2 + x2 - z2
        ] 

    faces = [
        (base+3, base+1, base+0, base+2),
        (base+6, base+4, base+5, base+7),
        (base+4, base+0, base+1, base+5),
        (base+7, base+3, base+2, base+6),
        (base+5, base+1, base+3, base+7),
        (base+6, base+2, base+0, base+4)
        ]

    return verts, faces

#Process the armature, goes through its bones and creates the mesh
def processArmature(context, arm, genVertexGroups = True):
    print("processing armature {0}".format(arm.name))

    #Creates the mesh object
    meshObj = meshFromArmature( arm )
    context.scene.objects.link( meshObj )

    verts = []
    edges = []
    faces = []
    vertexGroups = {}

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    try:
        #Goes through each bone
        for editBone in [b for b in arm.data.edit_bones if b.use_deform]:
            boneName = editBone.name
            print( boneName )
            poseBone = arm.pose.bones[boneName]

            #Gets edit bone informations
            editBoneHead = editBone.head
            editBoneTail = editBone.tail
            editBoneVector = editBoneTail - editBoneHead
            editBoneSize = editBoneVector.dot( editBoneVector )
            editBoneRoll = editBone.roll
            editBoneX = editBone.x_axis
            editBoneZ = editBone.z_axis
            editBoneHeadRadius = editBone.head_radius
            editBoneTailRadius = editBone.tail_radius

            #Creates the mesh data for the bone
            baseIndex = len(verts)
            baseSize = sqrt( editBoneSize )
            newVerts, newFaces = boneGeometry( editBoneHead, editBoneTail, editBoneX, editBoneZ, baseSize, editBoneHeadRadius, editBoneTailRadius, baseIndex )

            verts.extend( newVerts )
            faces.extend( newFaces )

            #Creates the weights for the vertex groups
            vertexGroups[boneName] = [(x, 1.0) for x in range(baseIndex, len(verts))]

        #Assigns the geometry to the mesh
        meshObj.data.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)

    except:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    else:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    #Assigns the vertex groups
    if genVertexGroups:
        for name, vertexGroup in vertexGroups.items():
            groupObject = meshObj.vertex_groups.new(name)
            for (index, weight) in vertexGroup:
                groupObject.add([index], weight, 'REPLACE')

    #Creates the armature modifier
    modifier = meshObj.modifiers.new('ArmatureMod', 'ARMATURE')
    modifier.object = arm
    modifier.use_bone_envelopes = False
    modifier.use_vertex_groups = True

    meshObj.data.update()

    return meshObj

class MeshFromArmatureOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world"
    bl_label = "MeshFromArmatureOperator"

    def execute(self, context):
        CreateMesh()        
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class( MeshFromArmatureOperator )
```

#### 2.8 Version

```python
import bpy
import mathutils 
from mathutils import Vector 
from math import *

def CreateMesh():

    obj = bpy.context.active_object

    if obj == None:
        print( "No selection" )
    elif obj.type != 'ARMATURE':
        print( "Armature expected" )
    else:
        processArmature( bpy.context, obj )

#Create the base object from the armature
def meshFromArmature( arm ):
    name = arm.name + "_mesh"
    meshData = bpy.data.meshes.new( name + "Data" )
    meshObj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, meshData )
    meshObj.matrix_world = arm.matrix_world.copy()
    return meshObj

#Create the bone geometry (vertices and faces)
def boneGeometry( l1, l2, x, z, baseSize, l1Size, l2Size, base ):
    x1 = x * baseSize * l1Size 
    z1 = z * baseSize * l1Size

#    x2 = x * baseSize * l2Size 
#    z2 = z * baseSize * l2Size
    
    x2 = Vector( (0, 0, 0) )
    z2 = Vector( (0, 0, 0) )

    verts = [
        l1 - x1 + z1,
        l1 + x1 + z1,
        l1 - x1 - z1,
        l1 + x1 - z1,
        l2 - x2 + z2,
        l2 + x2 + z2,
        l2 - x2 - z2,
        l2 + x2 - z2
        ] 

    faces = [
        (base+3, base+1, base+0, base+2),
        (base+6, base+4, base+5, base+7),
        (base+4, base+0, base+1, base+5),
        (base+7, base+3, base+2, base+6),
        (base+5, base+1, base+3, base+7),
        (base+6, base+2, base+0, base+4)
        ]

    return verts, faces

#Process the armature, goes through its bones and creates the mesh
def processArmature(context, arm, genVertexGroups = True):
    print("processing armature {0}".format(arm.name))

    #Creates the mesh object
    meshObj = meshFromArmature( arm )
    context.collection.objects.link( meshObj )

    verts = []
    edges = []
    faces = []
    vertexGroups = {}

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    try:
        #Goes through each bone
        for editBone in [b for b in arm.data.edit_bones if b.use_deform]:
            boneName = editBone.name
            print( boneName )
            poseBone = arm.pose.bones[boneName]

            #Gets edit bone informations
            editBoneHead = editBone.head
            editBoneTail = editBone.tail
            editBoneVector = editBoneTail - editBoneHead
            editBoneSize = editBoneVector.dot( editBoneVector )
            editBoneRoll = editBone.roll
            editBoneX = editBone.x_axis
            editBoneZ = editBone.z_axis
            editBoneHeadRadius = editBone.head_radius
            editBoneTailRadius = editBone.tail_radius

            #Creates the mesh data for the bone
            baseIndex = len(verts)
            baseSize = sqrt( editBoneSize )
            newVerts, newFaces = boneGeometry( editBoneHead, editBoneTail, editBoneX, editBoneZ, baseSize, editBoneHeadRadius, editBoneTailRadius, baseIndex )

            verts.extend( newVerts )
            faces.extend( newFaces )

            #Creates the weights for the vertex groups
            vertexGroups[boneName] = [(x, 1.0) for x in range(baseIndex, len(verts))]

        #Assigns the geometry to the mesh
        meshObj.data.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)

    except:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    else:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    #Assigns the vertex groups
    if genVertexGroups:
        for name, vertexGroup in vertexGroups.items():
            groupObject = meshObj.vertex_groups.new(name=name)
            for (index, weight) in vertexGroup:
                groupObject.add([index], weight, 'REPLACE')

    #Creates the armature modifier
    modifier = meshObj.modifiers.new('ArmatureMod', 'ARMATURE')
    modifier.object = arm
    modifier.use_bone_envelopes = False
    modifier.use_vertex_groups = True

    meshObj.data.update()

    return meshObj

class MeshFromArmatureOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world"
    bl_label = "MeshFromArmatureOperator"

    def execute(self, context):
        CreateMesh()        
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class( MeshFromArmatureOperator )
```

[Link to the blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2883/)

Comment: Would you be interested to submit this an official blender addon?

Comment: @Fire, currently I'm a bit out of all these. But if you think that's a good idea, feel free to do it (the code above is totally free to reuse ;)

Comment: For Blender 2.90 you must enable Developer Extras (User Preferences > Interface) so that "MeshFromArmature" will be searchable in the F3 menu.