# 2D- Bounding box around human model with sub meshes and armature

Tags: python, rendering, mesh, armature, camera

Mast is the entire model, It has sub meshes as can been seen from the figure, like eyes, clothes, but belonging to the same human model. I need to get the mesh of all of that together, so as to draw a 2d bounding box around the object on rendered image (like in this link [2d-bounding box on images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7198/save-the-2d-bounding-box-of-an-object-in-rendered-image-to-a-text-file/7203#7203]))

[image]

My object is a human model with armature , imported. I am trying to get 2D bounding box using the code [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7203/34973,) . In this only object meshes can be passed? How can I pass the complete model to this?

when I pass armature object, this gives 
**error** : **Object does not have geometry data** in the line

```
me = me_ob.to_mesh(scene, True, 'PREVIEW')
```

Is there any other way to do it?
Could some one please help?

Comment: You want the bounding box of the armature or mesh?

Comment: It seems the armature "Mast" is what you try to convert to a mesh. Armatures have no geometry and can not be converted directly with "to_mesh". If this is really the armature you want to convert, you can use a script like this one: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75040/convert-bones-to-meshes/75049#75049

Comment: @lemon Thanks, Actually no, not the armature. Mast is the entire model, It has sub meshes as can been seen from the figure, like eyes, clothes, but belonging to the same human model. i need to get the mesh of all of that together.

Comment: @Tak I need the bounding box for the whole model,(so, i think  armature +mesh), so that I get bounding boxes at each frames of animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this addon](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/myblendercontrib/master/create_bound_box.py) made by @sambler's answer found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14188/2517), which creates a bounding box for the selected objects. So you can select both armature and mesh in your script and modify the addon to get the bounding box data without creating the bounding box cube.

Comment: thanks for the link. Before I start,  can I also get the  2D bounding box of an object in rendered image ? Moreover , I need to do it via python script

Comment: @p.Neu I'm not sure about getting the bounding box in the rendered image. Better ask another question about that.

Comment: there is something already here [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7198/save-the-2d-bounding-box-of-an-object-in-rendered-image-to-a-text-file/7203#7203), but I can't  use it when I have a  group of meshes corresponding to one object,

Comment: @p.Neu then try commenting on codeman's answer and see if he can help you.

Comment: I don't have enough reputations to comment :(

Comment: @p.Neu may be try getting the bounding box in 3d view first and then check the rendering scenario

Comment: Thanks I would try that. I was thinking this solution by code man is very close to what I need. If you don't mind could you please add a comment for me?

Comment: @p.Neu done, hopefully he will get back to you.