# Bone to mesh - convert

Tags: mesh

I have seen this post [Convert bones to meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75040/convert-bones-to-meshes/75049) but i need just box (or cylinder), not a piramyd at every bone, can someone help me please?

Comment: you can change the appearence of your armature in the Properties panel > Object Data > Viewport Display > Display As, and choose for example B-Bone to diplay the bones as rectangles, the in Edit mode ctrl alt S to fatten or shrink the rectangles, also try the other appearences

Comment: I need to =convert= bone to mesh.

Comment: yes, I thought you found a solution with the link you gave

Comment: There the bone is replaced with pyramids, which, however, unfortunately, is not what I need. I suppose it needs to be changed from half a dozen lines of code, but I don't understand that.

Answer (score 6):

This is an update of [lemon's code](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75049/33589) on the question [Convert bones to meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75040/convert-bones-to-meshes/75049). Run the script and it will pop a menu asking if you want Pyramid, Tapered, or Box shapes. Pyramid is what the code did originally, tapered uses the bone envelope, and Box takes the average.

This image is "Box":
[image]

```python
# from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75049/33589

import bpy
import mathutils 
from mathutils import Vector 
from math import *

class ArmatureMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Mesh 2 Armature Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_Mesh_From_Armature"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("wm.mesh_from_armature", text="Pyramid").mesh_type = 'Pyramid' # from here
        layout.operator("wm.mesh_from_armature", text="Tapered").mesh_type = 'Tapered' # from here
        layout.operator("wm.mesh_from_armature", text="Box").mesh_type = 'Box' # from here

def CreateMesh(self, meshType):

    obj = bpy.context.active_object

    if obj == None:
        self.report({"ERROR"}, "No selection" )
    elif obj.type != 'ARMATURE':
        self.report({"ERROR"}, "Armature expected" )
    else:
        processArmature( bpy.context, obj, meshType = meshType )

#Create the base object from the armature
def meshFromArmature( arm ):
    name = arm.name + "_mesh"
    meshData = bpy.data.meshes.new( name + "Data" )
    meshObj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, meshData )
    meshObj.matrix_world = arm.matrix_world.copy()
    return meshObj

#Create the bone geometry (vertices and faces)
def boneGeometry( l1, l2, x, z, baseSize, l1Size, l2Size, base, meshType ):
    
    if meshType == 'Tapered':
        print(meshType)
        x1 = x * baseSize * l1Size 
        z1 = z * baseSize * l1Size

        x2 = x * baseSize * l2Size 
        z2 = z * baseSize * l2Size
    elif meshType == 'Box':
        print(meshType)
        lSize = (l1Size + l2Size) / 2
        x1 = x * baseSize * lSize 
        z1 = z * baseSize * lSize

        x2 = x * baseSize * lSize 
        z2 = z * baseSize * lSize

    else: # default to Pyramid
        print(meshType)
        x1 = x * baseSize * l1Size 
        z1 = z * baseSize * l1Size

        x2 = Vector( (0, 0, 0) )
        z2 = Vector( (0, 0, 0) )

    verts = [
        l1 - x1 + z1,
        l1 + x1 + z1,
        l1 - x1 - z1,
        l1 + x1 - z1,
        l2 - x2 + z2,
        l2 + x2 + z2,
        l2 - x2 - z2,
        l2 + x2 - z2
        ] 

    faces = [
        (base+3, base+1, base+0, base+2),
        (base+6, base+4, base+5, base+7),
        (base+4, base+0, base+1, base+5),
        (base+7, base+3, base+2, base+6),
        (base+5, base+1, base+3, base+7),
        (base+6, base+2, base+0, base+4)
        ]

    return verts, faces

#Process the armature, goes through its bones and creates the mesh
def processArmature(context, arm, genVertexGroups = True, meshType = 'Pyramid'):
    print("processing armature {0} {1}".format(arm.name, meshType) )

    #Creates the mesh object
    meshObj = meshFromArmature( arm )
    context.collection.objects.link( meshObj )

    verts = []
    edges = []
    faces = []
    vertexGroups = {}

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    try:
        #Goes through each bone
        for editBone in [b for b in arm.data.edit_bones if b.use_deform]:
            boneName = editBone.name
            # print( boneName )
            poseBone = arm.pose.bones[boneName]

            #Gets edit bone informations
            editBoneHead = editBone.head
            editBoneTail = editBone.tail
            editBoneVector = editBoneTail - editBoneHead
            editBoneSize = editBoneVector.dot( editBoneVector )
            editBoneRoll = editBone.roll
            editBoneX = editBone.x_axis
            editBoneZ = editBone.z_axis
            editBoneHeadRadius = editBone.head_radius
            editBoneTailRadius = editBone.tail_radius

            #Creates the mesh data for the bone
            baseIndex = len(verts)
            baseSize = sqrt( editBoneSize )
            newVerts, newFaces = boneGeometry( editBoneHead, editBoneTail, editBoneX, editBoneZ, baseSize, editBoneHeadRadius, editBoneTailRadius, baseIndex, meshType )

            verts.extend( newVerts )
            faces.extend( newFaces )

            #Creates the weights for the vertex groups
            vertexGroups[boneName] = [(x, 1.0) for x in range(baseIndex, len(verts))]

        #Assigns the geometry to the mesh
        meshObj.data.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)

    except:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    else:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    #Assigns the vertex groups
    if genVertexGroups:
        for name, vertexGroup in vertexGroups.items():
            groupObject = meshObj.vertex_groups.new(name=name)
            for (index, weight) in vertexGroup:
                groupObject.add([index], weight, 'REPLACE')

    #Creates the armature modifier
    modifier = meshObj.modifiers.new('ArmatureMod', 'ARMATURE')
    modifier.object = arm
    modifier.use_bone_envelopes = False
    modifier.use_vertex_groups = True

    meshObj.data.update()

    return meshObj

class MeshFromArmatureOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.mesh_from_armature"
    bl_label  = "MeshFromArmatureOperator"

    mesh_type : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="mesh_type")

    def execute(self, context):
        print('The mesh type is', self.mesh_type)
        CreateMesh(self, self.mesh_type)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class( ArmatureMenu )
    bpy.utils.register_class( MeshFromArmatureOperator )


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class( ArmatureMenu )
    bpy.utils.unregister_class( MeshFromArmatureOperator )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # The menu can also be called from scripts
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name='OBJECT_MT_Mesh_From_Armature')
```

Comment: I asked that [question on meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2734/duplicate-but-original-is-out-of-date) a couple of hours ago, but I guess no one reads meta. :)

Comment: I updated Lemon's answer (pending review). Only two lines actually changed, but I reflowed the code style from four spaces to triple back-ticks so it looks like all the lines changed.

Comment: Thanks! This works great in Blender 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This is an update of [Ron Jensen's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/190354/156898) (which is itself, as Ron points out, "an update of [lemon's code](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75049/33589) on the question [Convert bones to meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75040/convert-bones-to-meshes/75049)").

This update was to rework some of the GUI code since I was having some issues on my end with using it to properly choose the mesh type (i.e., Pyramid, Tapered, or Box). I've changed the GUI to be a pop-up dialog that uses [EnumProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) to pick which mesh type to use, and I've removed the ArmatureMenu class since I've changed the GUI to instead be called from the MeshFromArmatureOperator class when it is invoked (so now only 1 class has to be registered instead of 2).

Please note that I've only tested this in Blender 3.3.1 (which requires enabling "Developer Extras" in "Blender Preferences" -> "Interface" to be able to run "MeshFromArmatureOperator" from the F3 "Menu Search" window), so I can't vouch for compatibility with other versions.

```
# Built from:
# - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/190354
# - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75049/33589

import bpy
import mathutils 
from mathutils import Vector 
from math import *

def CreateMesh(self, meshType):

    obj = bpy.context.active_object

    if obj == None:
        self.report({"ERROR"}, "No selection" )
    elif obj.type != 'ARMATURE':
        self.report({"ERROR"}, "Armature expected" )
    else:
        processArmature( bpy.context, obj, meshType = meshType )

#Create the base object from the armature
def meshFromArmature( arm ):
    name = arm.name + "_mesh"
    meshData = bpy.data.meshes.new( name + "Data" )
    meshObj = bpy.data.objects.new( name, meshData )
    meshObj.matrix_world = arm.matrix_world.copy()
    return meshObj

#Create the bone geometry (vertices and faces)
def boneGeometry( l1, l2, x, z, baseSize, l1Size, l2Size, base, meshType ):
    
    if meshType == 'Tapered':
        print(meshType)
        x1 = x * baseSize * l1Size 
        z1 = z * baseSize * l1Size

        x2 = x * baseSize * l2Size 
        z2 = z * baseSize * l2Size
    elif meshType == 'Box':
        print(meshType)
        lSize = (l1Size + l2Size) / 2
        x1 = x * baseSize * lSize 
        z1 = z * baseSize * lSize

        x2 = x * baseSize * lSize 
        z2 = z * baseSize * lSize

    else: # default to Pyramid
        print(meshType)
        x1 = x * baseSize * l1Size 
        z1 = z * baseSize * l1Size

        x2 = Vector( (0, 0, 0) )
        z2 = Vector( (0, 0, 0) )

    verts = [
        l1 - x1 + z1,
        l1 + x1 + z1,
        l1 - x1 - z1,
        l1 + x1 - z1,
        l2 - x2 + z2,
        l2 + x2 + z2,
        l2 - x2 - z2,
        l2 + x2 - z2
        ] 

    faces = [
        (base+3, base+1, base+0, base+2),
        (base+6, base+4, base+5, base+7),
        (base+4, base+0, base+1, base+5),
        (base+7, base+3, base+2, base+6),
        (base+5, base+1, base+3, base+7),
        (base+6, base+2, base+0, base+4)
        ]

    return verts, faces

#Process the armature, goes through its bones and creates the mesh
def processArmature(context, arm, genVertexGroups = True, meshType = 'Pyramid'):
    print("processing armature {0} {1}".format(arm.name, meshType) )

    #Creates the mesh object
    meshObj = meshFromArmature( arm )
    context.collection.objects.link( meshObj )

    verts = []
    edges = []
    faces = []
    vertexGroups = {}

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    try:
        #Goes through each bone
        for editBone in [b for b in arm.data.edit_bones if b.use_deform]:
            boneName = editBone.name
            # print( boneName )
            poseBone = arm.pose.bones[boneName]

            #Gets edit bone informations
            editBoneHead = editBone.head
            editBoneTail = editBone.tail
            editBoneVector = editBoneTail - editBoneHead
            editBoneSize = editBoneVector.dot( editBoneVector )
            editBoneRoll = editBone.roll
            editBoneX = editBone.x_axis
            editBoneZ = editBone.z_axis
            editBoneHeadRadius = editBone.head_radius
            editBoneTailRadius = editBone.tail_radius

            #Creates the mesh data for the bone
            baseIndex = len(verts)
            baseSize = sqrt( editBoneSize )
            newVerts, newFaces = boneGeometry( editBoneHead, editBoneTail, editBoneX, editBoneZ, baseSize, editBoneHeadRadius, editBoneTailRadius, baseIndex, meshType )

            verts.extend( newVerts )
            faces.extend( newFaces )

            #Creates the weights for the vertex groups
            vertexGroups[boneName] = [(x, 1.0) for x in range(baseIndex, len(verts))]

        #Assigns the geometry to the mesh
        meshObj.data.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)

    except:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    else:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    #Assigns the vertex groups
    if genVertexGroups:
        for name, vertexGroup in vertexGroups.items():
            groupObject = meshObj.vertex_groups.new(name=name)
            for (index, weight) in vertexGroup:
                groupObject.add([index], weight, 'REPLACE')

    #Creates the armature modifier
    modifier = meshObj.modifiers.new('ArmatureMod', 'ARMATURE')
    modifier.object = arm
    modifier.use_bone_envelopes = False
    modifier.use_vertex_groups = True

    meshObj.data.update()

    return meshObj

class MeshFromArmatureOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.mesh_from_armature"
    bl_label  = "MeshFromArmatureOperator"

    mesh_type_items = [
        ("Pyramid", "Pyramid", ""),
        ("Tapered", "Tapered", ""),
        ("Box", "Box", ""),
    ]
    mesh_type: bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=mesh_type_items, name="Mesh Type")

    def execute(self, context):
        print('The mesh type is', self.mesh_type)
        CreateMesh(self, self.mesh_type)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class( MeshFromArmatureOperator )


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class( MeshFromArmatureOperator )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # The menu can also be called from scripts
    bpy.ops.wm.mesh_from_armature('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: JPLC thanks! the script work fine BUT is there a way to get the meshed bones to look exactly like the armature, no scaling

Comment: @SneekyChick someone would have to re-work the function boneGeometry() to build a more complicated shape.